# mysql getting data and looking it up in another table

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables in my database. Table 1 is a list of "timelines" and their corresponding owners and title.

Table 2 is a list of users who have access to the timelines but are followers, not owners.

I'm trying to write a query that outputs the lineID's and corresponding titles that are linked to a userID in either of the two tables.

```
A query for userID 1 would ideally output:

1 a
2 b
3 c
6 f
```

Hopefully this isn't too confusing but the purpose is to fill a dynamically generated select box with the LineID and Title for a given UserID...

```
Table 1 ("owners")
--------------------------
| LineID | UserID | Title |
| 1      | 1      | a     |
| 2      | 1      | b     |
| 3      | 1      | c     |
| 4      | 2      | d     |
| 5      | 2      | e     |
| 6      | 1      | f     |
--------------------------


Table 2 ("followers")
----------------------------
| RowID | LineID | UserID   |
| 1     | 1      | 1        |
| 2     | 1      | 2        |
| 3     | 3      | 1        |
| 4     | 3      | 2        |
| 5     | 2      | 2        |
| 6     | 6      | 1        |
----------------------------
```

I tried using:

```
SELECT title 
FROM `lines` 
LEFT JOIN follow 
    ON follow.user_id = lines.user_id 
WHERE follow.user_id = 1
```

That ended up producing duplicate rows.

The output I need would ideally be an array consisting of all the lineID's and Titles associated with that userID.

Comment: From your example, it looks like `SELECT * FROM lines WHERE UserID = 1` would do the trick.  Not sure I understand why both `LineID` and `UserID` are present in both tables.

Comment: basically: 

table 1 is a list of timelines and their corresponding owners and titles

using your query I would end up with a list of timelines created by userID 1 but it would not include the lines userID 1 is following as well

table 2 is a list of users who have access to change timelines but are not owners..just followers

Comment: You should update your question with the requirement you just explained to Eggyal.   And when you do that, use proper punctuation.  Your run on sentences are extremely difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   LineId, Title 
from     owners 
where    LineId in (select LineId from followers group by LineId ) 
order by owners.LineId
```

Comment: That seems to work well but there's no place to input a userID so it shows all the rows instead of just the rows with that userID.

Comment: As per requirement it is working fine because in followers table there is group by LineId

Comment: I need to get the results based on a specific userID. Your example doesn't have a place to put a userID so how could I run this query and get an output for userID1 and later run it for userID2? The results are always going to be the same no?

Comment: If you want result like this, you can directly get from Table1 using  query "select LineId, Title from owners where UserId = 1"